charactersiticUUID for writing data to connected bluetooth device
I am trying to transfer data from my .net maui app to another connected bluetooth device, using shiny.bluetoothLE. The app is meant to connect different devices and I am confused with characteristicsUUID that is required for writing data to another device.
Help appreciated!

The UUID depends on the Profile/Service you are writing to.
